# spring social xml config

Tags: spring, spring-social, xml-configuration

i have already read the spring social document but the part of configuration is Java based, but my project's configuration is xml based. so please tell me how config spring social in spring xml config file. thank you and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Please provide this code based config or, at least, link to it. Or even better: read documentation about code based configuration (http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) and port example by himself.

Comment: @Seongju - putting a little more effort into your question will yield better responses. You read the documentation, that's a good start. Now show what you've tried and you will certainly get good response.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code and issues will help us to provide you the best solution. Refer to the link below may be that is what you are looking for 
http://harmonicdevelopment.tumblr.com/post/13613051804/adding-spring-social-to-a-spring-mvc-and-spring

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example xml config

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a social config xml file and you have to import to your root-context.xml file. Also, you may think about configure your app with spring security. It's depends of your project architecture.

Sample spring social xml config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:social="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social"
       xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook" xmlns:bean="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/social http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd">

<!-- Ensures that configuration properties are read from a property file -->
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${sampleapp.appdir}/conf/appparam.txt"/>

<!--
    Configures FB and Twitter support.
-->
<facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}" />

<!--
    Configures the connection repository. This application uses JDBC
    connection repository which saves connection details to database.
    This repository uses the data source bean for obtaining database
    connection.
-->
<social:jdbc-connection-repository data-source-ref="sampleappDS" connection-signup-ref="accountConnectionSignup"/>



<!--
   This bean is custom account connection signup bean for your registeration logic.
    -->
    <bean id="accountConnectionSignup" class="com.sampleapp.social.AccountConnectionSignup"></bean>

<!--
    This bean manages the connection flow between the account provider and
    the example application.
-->
<bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="connectionRepository"/>
</bean>
```

Sample root-context.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<!-- Scan for Spring beans declared via annotations. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sampleapp"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:property-placeholder location="file:${sampleapp.appdir}/conf/appparam.txt"/>

<cache:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<import resource="security-config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:spring/bean-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:spring/persistence-config.xml"/>
<import resource="social-config.xml"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```