# Spring security + spring social xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I'm trying to figure out how exactly the Spring Social works and I decided to learn it by coding an example application.

The core of the app is based on appfuse quicksart archetype(multimodule, Spring MVC) which has a basic Spring Security already preconfigured.

I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/) which describes the intergration of Spring Social with Spring Security. However, the example uses java-based configuration for Spring Social - and as far as I know, the official documentation is mostly java-base too. This is my social.xml

```xml
    <!-- Ensures that configuration properties are read from a property file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*social.properties"/>

    <!--
        Configures FB support.
    -->
    <facebook:config app-id="${facebook.app.id}" app-secret="${facebook.app.secret}" />

    <social:jdbc-connection-repository data-source-ref="dataSource" connection-signup-ref="accountConnectionSignup"/>


    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <!--
       This bean is custom account connection signup bean for your registeration logic.
        -->
    <bean id="accountConnectionSignup" class="com.yoso.socialApp.service.impl.ConnectionSignupManagerImpl"></bean>

    <!--
        This bean manages the connection flow between the account provider and
        the example application.
    -->
    <bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="connectionRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
    factory-method="noOpText" />
</beans>
```

The xml configuration should be analogy to `SocialContext` from the mentioned tutorial and is based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344316/spring-social-xml-config).

The security.xml file is unchanged, I've added only this line

```
<intercept-url pattern="/auth" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
```

to the `html` tag.

I've also added a simple fb button to the login page, which redirects to `/auth/facebook` and added a reference to `social.xml` to `web.xml`. Now, the problem is that whenever I click on the fb button, nothing happens - the page just refreshes itself. No error, no message, not even in the server console.

Also, I'm not sure if I should create some controller for `/auth*` because according to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-social/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-socialauthenticationfilter-code), the `SocialAuthenticationFilter` should do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it actually worked for the whole time. I was testing it in a browser in non-anonymous window and I was logged to FB at the same time. So the app just redirected me to the login page (this was a little error in configuration as it was supposed to redirect me to the sign up page).

Lesson learned.